# Vue Js Form post issues to server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, vue.js, server

I am building a website and I cannot find a way to send my SignUp form data to my server using post. I tried with axios but it didn't work.
This is basically how my signup page looks like

```
<template>
  <div id = "app">
    <!-- <router-view /> -->
    <h1>{{ $t('signup') }}</h1>
    <p>{{ $t('signupMsg') }}</p>
    <b-form @submit="onSubmit" @reset="onReset" method="post" >
      <b-form-group
        id="input-group-1"
        label-for="input-1"
      >
      <p1> Name: </p1>
        <b-form-input
          id="input-1"
          v-model="form.name"
          required
          placeholder="Enter Name and Vorname"
        ></b-form-input>
      </b-form-group>

      <b-form-group id="input-group-2" label-for="input-2" >
        <p1>{{ $t('tech') }}</p1>
        <b-form-input
          id="input-2"
          v-model="form.technicianID"
          required
          placeholder="Enter assigned Technician ID"
        ></b-form-input>
      </b-form-group>
      <b-form-group id="input-group-3" label-for="input-3">
        <p1> Email ID: </p1>
        <b-form-input
          id="input-3"
          v-model="form.email"
          required
          placeholder="Enter assigned Email ID"
        ></b-form-input>
      </b-form-group>
      <b-form-group id="input-group-4" label-for="input-4">
        <p1> {{ $t('branch') }} </p1>
        <b-form-input
          id="input-4"
          v-model="form.branch"
          required
          placeholder="Enter your branch"
        ></b-form-input>
      </b-form-group>

      <!-- <b-button type="submit" > <router-link to="/requestsuccess">{{ $t('signup') }}</router-link> </b-button> -->
      <b-button type="submit" >{{ $t('signup') }} </b-button>
      <b-button type="reset" variant="danger">{{ $t('reset') }}</b-button>
      <router-link to="/" class="btn btn-link">{{ $t('back') }}</router-link>
    </b-form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'vue-axios'
export default {
  name: 'signup',

  data() {
      return {
        form: {
          name: '',
          technicianID: '',
          email:'',
          branch: ''
        }
    }
    },
    methods: {
      onSubmit(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault()
        axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: '/insert',
          data: this.form
          })
        .then(function (response) {
        //handle success
          console.log(response);
          })
        .catch(function (response) {
        //handle error
        console.log(response);
    });

      },
      onReset(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault()
        // Reset our form values
        this.form.name = ''
        this.form.technicianID = ''
        this.form.email = ''
        this.form.branch = ''
        // Trick to reset/clear native browser form validation state
        this.show = false
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.show = true
        })
      }
    }
}

</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style>
</style>
```

This is how my index.js looks like for post

```
router.post('/insert', function(req, res, next) {
  var item = {
    name: req.body.name,
    technicianID: req.body.technicianID,
    email: req.body.email,
    branch: req.body.branch
  };

  mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    db.collection('users').insertOne(item, function(err, result) {
      assert.equal(null, err);
      console.log('Item inserted');
      db.close();
    });
  });

  res.redirect('../components/requestsuccess');
});
```

I am fairly new to this but I can't find a way to send my data to the server.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Does your HTTP request reach to the server, do you get a response? Is there any error on the server or on your client?

Comment: Is there a way to find this out? I am really sorry but this is the first time I am doing something like this

Comment: You can attach a debugger to your back end server or log the responses and you can inspect that on the console of your server. You can also inspect the client's error from the dev tools of your browser.

Comment: In your server, you can: `console.log(req.body)`, you get some result or not in your server logs and then, why you get something like this `res.redirect('../components/requestsuccess')`

Comment: res.redirect('../components/requestsuccess') is a page I want to go after it finishes sending the data to server

Comment: You don't have to do it in backend, it's a job for frontend, that's way you're waiting for response from server in your axios `then` block.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code below:

**Backend:** You can change your backend with this code below

```js
router.post('/insert', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
  mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    db.collection('users').insertOne(req.body, function(err, result) {
      if(err) return res.status(500).send(err);
      return res.status(200).send(result.ops[0]);
      db.close();
    });
  });
});
```

> The code above only an example for simple case. If you want to add `assert`, then you can make sure it's working fine. If the simple code above it's working, then you can add `assert`.

Make sure you've been install `cors` on your server and add it in your `app.js` or `server.js` this code below:

```js
app.use(cord({origin: "*"});
```

And then, make sure you call your endpoint use: `http://`. Not only `localhost` but `http://localhost`.

**FrontEnd**

```
onSubmit(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault()
  axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: '/insert', // make sure your endpoint is correct
          data: this.form
      })
      .then(response => {
          //handle success
          console.log(response.data);
          // do some stuff here: redirect or something you want
      })
      .catch(error => {
          //handle error
          console.log(error.data);
      });
},
```

> Make sure your endpoint is correct.

I hope it can help you.

Comment: router.post('/insert'

Here /insert will be my endpoint right? Also It didn't work. I feel maybe the server and the frontend aren't connected

Comment: Yeah I tried that. It didn't work. I can't see any output in the console also

Comment: It says 
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8081/insert' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Now the new update on console is ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Also the Visual Studio Debugger shows 
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe bin\www.js
OPTIONS /insert 204 1.438 ms - 0
(node:50016) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
c:\Users\ajayr\Documents\liebherr-real\node_modules\mongodb\lib\topologies\server.js:294
          throw err;
          ^

Comment: Also 

TypeError: db.collection is not a function
    at c:\Users\ajayr\Documents\liebherr-real\src\router\index.js:26:8
    at executeCallback (c:\Users\ajayr\Documents\liebherr-

Comment: Can you provide your project github link? Then I can check it out for you.